# WPF Image only updates in run-time on last frame

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm new to XAML. I wrote following routine to rotate an image by a given angle (0 to 360). I put in a slider control to set the angle based on slider value. Works great! However, when running the program and clicking the 'spin' button,a For/Next loop goes from 0 to 360 and the image will only display the last angle rotation (360). I did put in a Sleep command to slow, just in case I wasn't catching the previous updates. Any help with why it won't update continuously would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Imports System.Threading.Thread
Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage

Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Slider1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of System.Double)) Handles Slider1.ValueChanged
' ---- when I adjust manually, this works perfectly
        Dim rotateTransform1 As New RotateTransform
        rotateTransform1.Angle = Slider1.Value
        lblAngle.Content = rotateTransform1.Angle
        Image1.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSpin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSpin.Click
    Dim spinAngle as Double
    For SpinAngle 0 to 360
            spinWheel(spinAngle)
            Sleep(50)
        Next spinAngle
    End Sub

    Private Sub spinWheel(ByVal spinAngle)
        Dim rotateTransform1 As New RotateTransform
        rotateTransform1.Angle = SpinAngle 'Slider1.Value
       Image1.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1
        lblAngle.Content = rotateTransform1.Angle
        Image1.InvalidateVisual()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ' Image1.createOption = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache

    End Sub

End Class

XAML

<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="677" Width="910">
    <Grid Background="#FF006903">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="238*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="178*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="SPIN!" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="521,101,0,0" Name="btnSpin" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="15" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
        <Image Height="615" Margin="32,7,0,0" Name="Image1" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               RenderTransformOrigin=" 0.5,0.5"    Source="/rotatePicture;component/Images/purp_wheel_cropped.png"
               Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="619" />

        <Slider Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="127,188,0,0" Name="Slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Maximum="360" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="521,175,0,0" Name="lblAngle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="15" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
        <Image Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="535,252,0,0" Name="Image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Source="/rotatePicture;component/Images/wheel_pointer.png" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It's entirely possible that your sleep is too short. How high have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you are **blocking the UI thread** by repeatedly calling `Sleep` in a Click handler. WPF provides a very elegant mechanism for what you are trying to do. It's called [Animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx).

A method that animates the rotation of a `FrameworkElement` may look like shown below in C# (sorry, but I don't speak VB).

```
private void RotateElement(
    FrameworkElement element, double from, double to, TimeSpan duration)
{
    var transform = element.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
    if (transform != null)
    {
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation(from, to, duration);
        transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
    }
}
```

Note that the `RotateTransform` must already be contained in the `RenderTransform` property of the `FrameworkElement`. It could for example be assigned in XAML like this:

```
<Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ...>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

You would call the `RotateElement` method in a Button Click handler like this:

```
private void btnSpin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RotateElement(Image1, 0, 360, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(360 * 50));
}
```

---

Note also that in your `Slider1_ValueChanged` it is also not necessary to create a new `RotateTransform` every time.

Moreover, there is rarely any need to call `InvalidateVisual`, as you do in `spinWheel`.

Answer (score 0):

Clemens answer is good. Do not forget that you can pause/resume animations but only if you create them in code-behind. If I remember correctly you can't control animations if you start them in XAML.

Comment: Saying "another answer is good" is not itself an answer to the question. You may write this as comment to my answer instead if you feel that there is something more to say about animations.

Comment: I don't have enough privileges to do that. Maybe allow newer users to comment in the first place ? http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment